# Is it possible to apply $last and $odd to the same element, in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to apply a style to the last element if its index is odd and numbered.

I tried:

```
ng-class="'$last'?('$odd'?'w-200':''):''"
```

But this applies the style to every element.

How would I go about fixing this?
Thanks

Comment: `ng-class="{'w-200': $last && $odd}"`  or, depending on your angular version `ng-class-odd="{'w-200': $last}"`

Comment: thanks. I had tried the first one earlier , maybe i had some syntax error . but it works to an extent now. It does not apply the style to an array which has only one element . I wonder why

Comment: Possibly because the first row is $$index==0, therefore not odd?

Comment: but that makes every odd element even then, like 3rd element is $$index == 2

Comment: can i use equality operator in ng-style, something like $last == $first ?

Comment: Should be able to: `ng-class="{'w-200': ($last && $odd) || ($last && $first)}"`

Answer (score 0):

Change your code:

```
ng-class="'$last'?('$odd'?'w-200':''):''"
```

TO

```
ng-class="{'w-200': ($last && $odd) || ($last && $first)}"
```

Above logic will only apply class `w-200` for last element with odd index.